# Cannot import Sklearn from sklearn.externals.joblib

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda, joblib

I am a beginner and I just started with machine learning. I am trying to import classes like `imputer` from `sklearn` but i am unable to do it.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer,LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder,StandardScaler
```

> ImportError: cannot import name '**version**' from
>   'sklearn.externals.joblib'
>   (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib__init__.py)

Comment: The first idea would be to check that sklearn and joblib are both installed and up to date. Try `python -m pip install sklearn --upgrade` and `python -m pip install joblib --upgrade`. Can you provide a full error report?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem.
I have replaced

`from sklearn.externals import joblib`

with

`import joblib`

and it works fine in Python 3.7.2

Comment: It worked for me to. May i know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 6):

I believe there was an update on Scikit-learn that render that import unusable.

I had my local installation to be version `0.20.3` and this import is pefectly working. But on my server I have installation `0.23.1` and this error pop up. Something must be chaging in the new version.

For my case, use `import joblib` fix the problem. In your case it seems more complicated. This sounds very much likeky to be caused if you have more than one Scikit-learn version installed on your system. You need to uninstall all of them and do a clean install of sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

The problem sometimes happens due to the version. This may help:
If you has written like this

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```

Modify it as this:

```
import joblib
```

Answer (score -1):

Try 
        `python -m pip install sklearn --upgrade` 
and 
        `python -m pip install joblib --upgrade`

and then, use this :
`import joblib`

Good luck.

Comment: I have applied your method, i have python 3.8 and scikit-learn 0.23.2 and your commands are not working

Answer (score -1):

```
import joblib
```

This works for me. Actually I was having that kinda challenge